# I have images set to absolute positioning, with percentage settings, but one image still doesn't stay when the window is resized

Tags: css, html, css-position, window-resize

I have set up a div with many images inside. They are all set to absolute, and they all have top and right set to percentages. All the images stay the same when the window is resized except for one.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a268w7ez/

Or, I've put in the key code below.

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="space">
   <div id="map">
    <img id="layer9" src="./assets/css/images/layer9.png">
    <img id="layer8" src="./assets/css/images/layer8.png">
    <img id="layer7" src="./assets/css/images/layer7.png">
    <img id="layer6" src="./assets/css/images/layer6.png">
    <img id="layer5" src="./assets/css/images/layer5.png">
    <img id="layer4" src="./assets/css/images/layer4.png">
    <img id="layer3" src="./assets/css/images/layer3.png">
    <img id="layer2" src="./assets/css/images/layer2.png">
    <img id="layer1" src="./assets/css/images/layer1.png">
    <img id="cantonica" class="planet" src="./assets/css/images/dot.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
#map {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 2%;
height: 76%;
width: 33%;
margin: auto;
z-index: 0;
}
#layer9 {
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
#layer8 {
height: 90.11553273427471%;
position: absolute;
top: 5.006418485237484%;
left: 3.465982028241335%;
z-index: 2;
}

// The #layer id's go on like this with different heights, tops, and 
// lefts, all set in percentages.

.planet {
width: 10px;
}
#cantonica {
position: absolute;
top: 12.195121951219512%;
right: 14.120667522464696%;
z-index: 10;
}
```

It looks correct at first on my browser, the white dot image is in the right spot:
[image: Correct Layout]

But when I resize the window, everything stays in the same spot except the white dot:
[image: Incorrect Layout]

I am going to be adding MANY more dots (50+), so it's really important that I can resize the window and they all stay in the same spot.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please post your code in a fiddle or similar. That would be the most effective way for us to provide assistance

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a268w7ez/ thank you for the advice! here is the link, and I've updated my question as well

Answer (score 0):

Following your pattern, it looks like you want every lower layer to be a little bit bigger than the previous one. Because you've applied a `height: 100%;` to `layer9`, I'm assuming that that layer is going to be the full size of the container.

You can use the same CSS styling that you've used on all the other layers, but just make it the full size of its container:

```
#layer9 {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The problem was caused because you applied a `relative` position to `layer9`, which means it's going to shrink or grow in size if the height is a percentage (100%).

[**Updated JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/a268w7ez/2/)

Comment: in the updated JSFiddle, the dot is still moving when I resize the window.

Comment: That is because that little planet is much further away from the other images in terms of % *relative* to their parent (`#map`), so if the screen shrinks/grows, so does the map, because the map also has a width in percentage. [**Demonstration**](https://i.imgur.com/HRoLhg1.gifv). I have changed the size of the map into a fixed height and width, it will look like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/a268w7ez/5/). But note that the individual layers won't move separately anymore, which is probably something you wanted.